# LINQ query for Dictionary items in C#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a Dictionary where on of the members of DetailedObject is a List. I am trying to write a query against the Dictionary to return all of the items where the DetailedObject has a specific value for one of the fields in it's SubStructure. For example:

```
public struct SubStructure
{
  public int Id;
  public string SubSpecificFile;
}

public class DetailedObject  
{
  public int Id;
  public List<SubStructure> subs = new List<SubStructure>();
}

public Dictionary<int, DetailedObject> dict = new Dictionary<string, DetailedObject>();
```

Each SubStructure can appear inside zero or more DetailedObject instances.

I would, for example, like to query "dict" for each DetailedObject whose "subs" collection contains a SubStructure item with the Id of 3.

Comment: Any good reason why you're using a struct for SubStructure?

Comment: Using a struct because it is only going to contain data. No additional processing required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var result = dict1.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.subs.Any(ss => ss.Id == 3));
```

Comment: If you add `ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)` to the end you end up with a dictionary again.

Comment: what if I want to get a collection (e.g. .ToList()) of the 'SubSpecificFile' variables related with Id ==3 ?

Answer (score 7):

```
dict.Values.Where(d => d.subs.Any(ss => ss.Id == 3))
```

Comment: This way you miss the `Key` of each dictionary entry.

Comment: Quoting OP: 'query "dict" for each DetailedObject'... no requirement to get the key.